# What is the difference between reindexall() vs reindexeverything() in magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, indexer

I would like to know what the difference is between `reindexAll()` and `reindexEverything()` in Magento indexer?

Answer (score 0):

`reindexEverything()` appears to check and use depends prior to moving on to `reindexAll()`

Comment: A little more info would be useful here

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments in Magento 1.9...

```php
    /**
     * Reindex all data what this process responsible is
     * Check and using depends processes
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function reindexEverything()
    {
```

and

```php
    /**
     * Rebuild all index data
     */
    public function reindexAll()
    {
        $this->_getResource()->reindexAll();
    }
```

But you'll only use reindexall or reindexallrequired when running `php shell/indexer.php`, as follows:

```
$ php shell/indexer.php --help
Usage:  php -f indexer.php -- [options]

  --status <indexer>            Show Indexer(s) Status
  --mode <indexer>              Show Indexer(s) Index Mode
  --mode-realtime <indexer>     Set index mode type "Update on Save"
  --mode-manual <indexer>       Set index mode type "Manual Update"
  --reindex <indexer>           Reindex Data
  info                          Show allowed indexers
  reindexall                    Reindex Data by all indexers
  reindexallrequired            Reindex Data only if required by all indexers
  help                          This help

  <indexer>     Comma separated indexer codes or value "all" for all indexers
```

Answer (score 0):

In Magento, the **reindexall()** method is used to rebuild all indexers. This method can be used to rebuild all indexers at once, rather than rebuilding them individually.

On the other hand, the **reindexEverything()** method is used to rebuild all indexers, as well as perform some additional tasks such as clearing the cache and updating the configuration. This method can be useful if you want to perform a complete rebuild of all indexers and update the system configuration in a single operation.

*It's worth noting that both of these methods should be used with caution, as they can be resource-intensive and may take a long time to complete, depending on the size of your store and the number of indexers that need to be rebuilt. It's generally a good idea to use these methods during off-peak hours or when there is minimal traffic on your store to avoid any potential disruption to your customers.*